# How I can pass target='_blank' into a link inside of flash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
flash[:notice] = "Posts have been queued for processing. <a href='#{@message.url[0]}index9999.html' class='flink' target='_blank'>First Post</a>"
```

This works with the exception that `target='_blank'` is not being passed into the links.

Answer (score 0):

Update to:

```
flash[:notice] = "Posts have been queued for processing. <a href='#{@message.url[0]}index9999.html' class='flink' target='_blank'>First Post</a>"
```

Simply needed to finish off the quotes...

Update: I'm confused as to how it actually would have worked at all... Hm... the solution may not be as simple as I proposed but let me know and I can help troubleshoot more...

Comment: the missing quote was just a typo (otherwise none of it would have worked).